# mvc site map dropdown menu not working properly

Tags: css, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, sitemap

**webconfig**

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap" />
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

**mvc.sitemap**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Log In" controller="Auth" action="LogIn" visibility="!Auth">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Log In (vertical form)" controller="Auth" action="LogInVerticalForm" visibility="!Auth" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Hobby" clickable="false">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="User Mgmt" controller="Home" action="Football" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Role Mgmt" controller="Home" action="RoleMgmt" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Account" controller="User" action="Account" visibility="Member,Manager,Supervisor" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Users" controller="Admin" action="UserList" visibility="Admin" >
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit User" controller="Admin" action="EditUser"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-submenu {
 position: relative;
   }
     // Default dropdowns
     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
     top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -6px;
       margin-left: -1px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
      border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;

   }
  .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
   }

  // Dropups
  .dropup .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: -2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
       border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    }

   // Caret to indicate there is a submenu
   .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
   display: block;
   content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: darken(@dropdownBackground, 20%);
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
   }
   .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
    border-left-color: @dropdownLinkColorHover;
   }

   // Left aligned submenus
   .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
   // Undo the float
   // Yes, this is awkward since .pull-left adds a float, but it sticks to                  our conventions elsewhere.
   float: none;


    > .dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
         border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
      }
     }


    .dropdown .dropdown-menu .nav-header {
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
      }
```

menu looks like this right now:
https://postimg.org/image/nqfzmbka9/

but I want to make a menu like this one: https://postimg.org/image/4qymp4odj/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To identify a possible problem it is necessary that you describe what exactly the problem is. What should the menu/sitemap look like? And yes, you should definitely provide the CSS you coded. Furthermore if you need to post an image please upload it to StackOverflow - not anywhere else. In the question editor you can click on the image icon.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/asp-net-mvc-5-menu-using-site-map-provider-bootstrap-3-navbar/) can help. If not you should provide the HTML code that is generated by the *MvcSiteMapProvider*.